# How do you teleport an item using a command block when the item is in a certain spot?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-education-edition

I am making a one block skyblock that is going very well except the items fall off the edge when they shouldn't because a command block should teleport the item to the infinity block, but they aren't. Why and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

to avoid this, put a random command block somewhere out of sight, forceload its chunk by running this command while standing atop of the command block:
`tickingarea add ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ commandsarea`,
don't move the command block, then change the command to

`run tp @e[type=item, y<0] x y z`
and set it to repeating and always active. X Y and Z are the coords you should fill in for the place you want the items to come back to.

Comment: I don't believe `y<0` is valid, could you verify this?

Comment: i think you mean y=0